# Difference between __str__(self) and show(self)

Tags: python

Just encountered an example Fraction class and am not too sure what the difference between these two methods is. Once `__str__` has been implemented doesn't `show` become redundent ?

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)

def show(self):
    print(self.num,"/",self.den)
```

I realise `__str__` is a *magic* method who's implementation takes care of any context that requires a string version of the class. Just can't see the point of the `show(self)` method ?

---

EDIT

Is show a generic method that most classes require?
My problem is if I have a fraction x then all I need do is `print(x)` and I will see `1\2` or what ever the instance holds - so why would one ever bother implementing an additional method `show` ?

Comment: One returns, the other prints.

Comment: @StefanoBorini I know ... but see edit to OP. Once `__str__` has been implemented the `show` method seems a bit redundent. Trying to work out why it in the class example in my test book? Is `show` a standard method implemented in most classes?

Comment: @whytheq: no, none of the standard classes implement it.

Comment: You are right, it is a bit redundant. There is no convention to use `show()` in Python. I don't think you'll find any magic answers here.

Comment: @Bogdan thanks - suppose my question could have been a little more specific but it is nice to get this extra information concerning the `__str__` magic method. Not sure why I've been marked down so much though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of having a `__str__` method is to create a string representation of the object. `__str__` *should* return a string. If the implementation of `__str__` instead *printed* the string representation and returned nothing, when the object was used in a string context a `TypeError` will be raised. Take for example:

```
def __str__(self):
        print '%f/%f'%(self.num,self.den)
```

If we went to display a fraction object like so:

```
f = Fraction(1,2)
print f
```

we get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/...", line 13, in <module>
    print f
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
>>>
```

This is because `__str__` is used to ***get*** the string representation of the object, not print it (by convention that is, you could print as long as you return a string). That's what the `print` statment/function is used for in conjunction with a `__str__` method.

On the other hand a method like `show`:

```
def show(self):
        print(self.num,"/",self.den) #or even print(self) (for the last part of answer)
```

Is essentially equivalent to `print(f)` in the above case (except it includes spaces next to the operands). `show` is used to *output* the string representation, while `__str__` to *get* the representation.

However, additional logic may be added to `show` which isn't appropriate/necessary when constructing a string representation, and hence make sense to have both methods.

You can however use a method like `show` where a `print` statement is inappropriate i.e:

```
if f.show(): pass
if print(f): pass #raise exception
```

Comment: +1 thanks for all the extra info - one a down-voted question as well! (not too sure why such negativity from people as the question is relatively precise but also generic enough to have some use)

Comment: ...out oan aside - what is `: pass` ?

Comment: @whytheq `pass` is "do nothing", equivalent of empty braces in languages like Java or C++, as python parses code logic through indentation it needs some command to express "nothingness" (you would get a parse error if you just omit it)

Answer (score 4):

The `__str__` method is being very careful to make sure everything is a `str` and so it returns a `str`.

The `show` method is relying on print to convert `self.num` and `self.den` to str implicitly. It displays the result as a side-effect, and returns None

`print` will insert a space between each parameter.

```
>>> str(3)+"/"+str(5)
'3/5'
>>> print(3,"/",5)
3 / 5
```

If you don't care about the extra spaces, there's really no reason not to use

```
def show(self):
    print(self)
```

perhaps the author thinks it's clearer not to do it that way.

Decoupling `show` and `__str__` this way may also be surprising when you try to make a subclass. If the subclass overrides `__str__`, you would probably expect the change to be reflected in `show` too.

Comment: +1 thanks gnibbler - I'd noticed the extra white space - can we amend ` print(3,"/",5)` to force it to not insert those extra spaces?   p.s. why has my OP got marked down ...it is clear and general; not the cleverest question ever but not a down-vote situation.

Comment: print("%d/%d" % (3,5))

Comment: @SteveBarnes thanks: so the comma form of the `print` function lends itself better to creating sentences.

Comment: No a trailing comma replaces the newline that would normally follow a print, by default items separated by commas in a print call will be space separated, if you would like something else either use join, specify a separator or use % formats for the ultimate of control.

Answer (score 3):

`__str__` is a magic method that will be called each time object will be treated as string, for example `str(fraction_instance)`

Comment: +1 thanks Anton. I've edited the OP - my question is more to do with `show` as I'm just checking if it is a common method that people implement. Apologies if the intent of the original question was a little vague.